# getting error error setting mempool handle:: Invalid argument

Tags: dpdk

I am trying to migrate my code from dpdk version 17.11 to dpdk 19.11. I am seeing this error when i try to create a mbuf pool.
The error returned is `Invalid argument`. What am i missing here ?

Code Snippet:

```
struct rte_mempool *pktmbuf_pool = rte_pktmbuf_pool_create("mbuf_pool", NB_MBUF, MEMPOOL_CACHE_SZ, 0, MBUF_DATA_SZ, rte_socket_id());
```

[Logs]

1. Platform - x86_64
2. Library Mode - shared
3. error reason - EINVAL

Comment: How is that programming question?  Show us some code.

Comment: what else would you classify it as ?

Comment: ```struct rte_mempool *pktmbuf_pool =
     rte_pktmbuf_pool_create("mbuf_pool", NB_MBUF, MEMPOOL_CACHE_SZ, 0,
        MBUF_DATA_SZ, rte_socket_id());```. This was the piece of code. that was failing. I was missing a eal parameter . It was fixed by adding a -d librte_mempool_ring.so command line parameter.

Comment: I know nothing about dpdk and website didn't clue me in when I checked.  Initial question had no code and why I suggested you clarified it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please share the following inforamtion 1) 64 or 32 bit, 2) Huge page allocated and shared 3) Platform, 4) EAL Args passed, 5) logs by running with --log-level=8 6) reason for failure using rte_strerror

Comment: The error I got using rte_errno was EINVAL  it was in a 64 bit system with huge paged allocated. I was missing the ''-d librte_mempool_ring.so" in the eal args once I passed that things started working

Comment: @AmitLimaye please accept and upvote to close the question, as it will help others to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

DPDK `rte_pktmbuf_pool_create` can be created in `RING mode or STACK Mode`. The default mode is ring mode alloc-free. If the Applications are built in shared library mode, one needs to pass the requested library or path to the library using EAL option `-d`.

Note: This is valid from DPDK 19.11 LTS onwards as `libdpdk.so` is just a file which holds the names of libraries built for.

Solution:

1. Modify EAL args with the option `-d` for `mempool_ring`
2. Modify the LDFLAGS to include `mempool_ring` (similar to testpmd) to avoid passing EAL arg option `-d`.

[EDIT-1] as updated in a comment the problem is resolved for @AmitLimaye by passing `-d librte_mempool_ring.so`